# scrapy : move code to pipelines.py have exceptions.NameError

Tags: python, scrapy

this is my main code

```
class ProductSpider(Spider):
    name = "email"
    start_urls = []

    def __init__(self):
        ScrapyFileLogObserver(open("spider.log", 'w'), level=log.INFO).start()             
        ScrapyFileLogObserver(open("spider_error.log", 'w'), level=log.ERROR).start()      
        super(ProductSpider, self).__init__()
```

And I want to move the `__init__` part to pipeline.py `def open_spider(self, spider)` part

Like this :

```
class ShopPipeline(object):
    def open_spider(self, spider):
        ScrapyFileLogObserver(open("spider.log", 'w'), level=log.INFO).start()             
        ScrapyFileLogObserver(open("spider_error.log", 'w'), level=log.ERROR).start()      
        super(ProductSpider, self).__init__()
```

But I don't know how to edit the `super(ProductSpider, self).__init__()`
The error said  `exceptions.NameError: global name 'ProductSpider' is not defined`

How can I edit this Please guide me Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to have a `super(ProductSpider, self).__init__()` call in the `open_spider()`:

```
class ShopPipeline(object):
    def open_spider(self, spider):
        ScrapyFileLogObserver(open("spider.log", 'w'), level=log.INFO).start()             
        ScrapyFileLogObserver(open("spider_error.log", 'w'), level=log.ERROR).start()
```

[`open_spider()`](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/item-pipeline.html#open_spider) is a method that is called when the spider is opened.